# Django or pylon portability to python 3 will affect my app?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, portability

I want to make my app, in django or pylons, but I came to know that Django will be supporting Python 3 in near future. So I want to know that if I will update Django that will have python3 supported then to support python 3, what changes I will need to do? Or it will be all things done by people who are developing Django and I will not need to do some changes? And is it possible to update django? And is Django more easily portable than Pylons?

If I will update Django with Python 3 in future then what sort of changes can be required by me? Will it be 35% rework? Except it I think I will have rails as a choice.

Please suggest.

thanks

Comment: This question makes little sense.  Are you just asking for some sort of random confirmation?  Django will probably still support Python 2 for quite a while, given that it will take time for existing apps to port to Python 3 and the new version of Django.  Asking on the Django mailing list might get you more accurate information.  In any case, what guarantee do you have that the next version of rails will not be 35% re-work?

Comment: Rails 3 have already some new things and ruby doesnot have backward compatibility problems that seems in Python. Before starting work , I just want to make sure that I can continue my app. on python 3 supported Django without much rework, this is what I am asking. Rails seems to be better framework but Python community seems to be much better and quicker.

Comment: A lot of people are using Django regardless of this Python 2 to Python 3 issue.  If you write your code properly, the [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) script should do most of what you need (e.g. module renames, etc.).  What do you want to hear?

Comment: So python 2-3 isn't a big issue right, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being future proof is impossible, and all software that doesn't exist should be viewed as vapourware. Use what works now, today for you. Ignore what may exist tomorrow.